# Form Background Image within a Site.Master

Tags: asp.net, image, background, master-pages

I have tried everything to get an image to display as a background. I have it working on my local visual studio express install but when I upload to internet host server it will not render properly. I had the same problem with a header background image but found a solution that works, but same solution will not work with form background.

If I place the same background image style tags in the     `div class="page"`, it will render on both my development environment and internet host servers, but I want my page over top of this image (i.e. my application code pages are on top of this background image.

Any ideas or Suggestions?

Site.Master Code Snippet

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="MyApp.SiteMaster" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title><%=Page.Title %></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link id="Link1" runat="server" rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
    <link id="Link2" runat="server" rel="icon" href="~/favicon.ico" type="image/ico"/>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

    <script runat="server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
     /* this code statement below is what I used to solve the header banner issue 
        but does not work for form background
     */
    public string imgHeaderPath = System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Images/water-banner.jpg");


</script>
</head>
<body >
 <form runat="server" style="background-position: left top;  background-repeat: repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-image: url('/Images/willnotdisplay.jpg')">

    <div class="page">

          <div class="header" style="background-image: url('<%= imgHeaderPath %>')">     
            <div class="title">                
                    <h1>&nbsp;<asp:Localize ID="Localize1" runat="server"  Text="<%$ Resources:Resource, Title %>" /></h1>
            </div>
.
.
.
```

Comment: I think you answered this indirectly, but just to be sure: Can you access the image directly on the production server, i.e. navigating to 'foo.com/Images/willnotdisplay.jpg'?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yes actually I can, but in doing so I noticed my path was not 100% correct. locally it was root/images and on server it was foo.com/registration/images . I had tried using the ~/images/ but that did not work. When I hard code the /registration/image directory it works.

Comment: I'm somewhat new to this, but I could see the folder disparity causing a variety of issues. Is it possible for you to move your images into the same folder either on the server or on your local machine?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do

```
<div class="header" style="background-image: url('/Images/water-banner.jpg')">
```

without the overhead of using **imgHeaderPath**

This will probably not show on your dev machine

Alternately you can add the following to your site.css file

```
div.header {background-image: url('/Images/water-banner.jpg');}
```

and remove the style attribute on the div which should work on both Dev and Production